# You are stopping by Timmy’s to buy $12$ donuts. There are $4$ varieties to choose from.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

You are stopping by Timmy’s to buy $12$ donuts. There are $4$ varieties to choose from. You need to
have at least one donut from each variety. How many different ways can you select your $12$ donuts?

Comment: Affine, abstract, projective and quasi-projective?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312337/find-the-number-of-positive-integers-solutions-of-the-equation-3x2y-37

Comment: As the linked post suggests, the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) technique will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

1. Taking $1$ donut firstly from each variety to fulfill The condition for at least one donut from each variety, so we have $4$ donuts selected. $12-4 = 8$ donuts remain to be selected.
2. Now we can select $8$ donuts with any number of donuts from each variety(including zero selections), consider the $4$ varieties to be named $a,b,c,d$ then we have the situation as $a+b+c+d = 8$. Here $r = 4$ (four varieties) and $n = 8 $

So, to find the number of ways($w$) in this situation use $w = \binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$. applying this, we get the result as $\binom{11}{3}$ which is equal to $165$.

Answer (score 1):

It will be

$$\binom{11}{3}=\frac{11\cdot10\cdot9}{3\cdot2\cdot1}=11\cdot5\cdot9=165$$

Consider the $8$ remaining donuts as $8$ points (because you have at least $1$ donut for each different donut type, so quit $4$ donuts of your $12$).

$$\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet$$

Then you can separate your remaining $8$ donuts by three bars to identify each of your four types of donuts. For example:

$$\bullet\mid\bullet\mid \bullet\bullet\bullet\mid\bullet\bullet\bullet$$

So if you consider those three bars with the $8$ points all as points again, you will only have to choose three of the new $11$ points to change them by bars and get another arrangement.

Comment: The correct answer is 165.

Comment: Thanks I didn't read that consideration.